# How to pass a property to an event with a Button

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm generating buttons dynamically that I want it to call a method like this:

```
private function fetchTheDay(day:String):void {
...             
}
```

But I wasn't sure how to make the button pass the string to it

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fetchTheDay);
buttonVGroup.addElement(button);
```

trying to do something like this didn't work:

```
 button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fetchTheDay(myString));
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an inline function for this, it's the simplest solution:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fetchTheDay(myString));
});
```

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: This link provides a bit better solution along the same concept http://nwebb.co.uk/blog/?p=243